# Mongodb Index: why field dateStr like 2022-12-30 is faster than Date?

Tags: mongodb

We have a collection holding 20M+ documents. It's a frequent operation to query it by time range.
Also there are some other fields like type, category.

We found if we search data in long range, like a month, with `{modified: {$gte: new Date("2022-12-01"), $lte: new Date("2022-12-31")}, ...}`, it costs more than `{modifiedStr: {$gte: "2022-12-01", $lte: "2022-12-31"}, ...}`.
Of course they both hits their indexes.

According my knowledge, index on Date field has better carinality than date string.

Counld anyone give us a explaination on this? Or this is just a illusion.

Will B+ tree depth be the answer?

Comment: Maybe try to drop both indexes and create both of them from scratch. And be aware, when you run one query, then the data is cached in RAM, so the second one might be faster due to that. And maybe a stupid question: is the result the same?

Comment: Can you provide more details like how you benchmark the performance for the indexes?

Comment: Which query did you run first?  If all of the documents are already in the cache from the first query, the second one can skip all of the disk reads and save time.